# How to properly alert database records using Fetch javascript API and php

Tags: javascript, php

Am trying to fetch and **alert id** and **name** records from database using Javasript fetch API.

**My issue** is that nothing is alerted as the alert is empty.

I Think there is an issue with this line of code

```
response.json().then(
```

.
**Here is the sample of json that is return by database**

```
[{"id":"5","name":"moore Lizzy"}]
```

**here is the fetch API Javascript**

```
fetch("http://localhost/record/rec.php", {
  "method": "GET",
}).then(
  response => {
    response.json().then(
      data => {
        console.log(data);

        data.forEach((r) => {
          alert(r.id);
          alert(r.name);
        });
      }
    )
  })
```

**here is the php code**

```
//connect db

$id = "5";
$name = "More Lizy";
                
$result_arr[] = array(
"id" => $id,
"name" => $name
);

echo json_encode($result_arr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax above is not quite correct. You are chaining the `.next()` directly to the `response.json()` - ie `response.json().then(` where it should be more like the following (slightly abbreviated ) where the `.next()` is bound to the entire previous `next()` portion that returns the JSON

```
fetch( '/record/rec.php' )
    .then( r=>r.json() )
    .then( json=>{
        Object.keys( json ).forEach(k=>{
            alert( `${k} - ${json[k]}` )
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding **return** to the codeline here also solved the issue. lastly, I also ensured that there is no **white spacing** in the code.

```
return response.json().then(
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {"method": "GET",})
        .then(async (response) => {
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log("data: ", data)
        })
```